# ASP.NET is it possible to access public page variables from ListView.EmptyDataTemplate?

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to access public page variables from ListView.EmptyDataTemplate ?

Can i do that and if can, how ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically with:

```
 <%= this.YourPagesPublicProperty%>
```

Example, my ASP.NET File:

```
<p>IntDicIsEmptyValue: <%= this.IntDicIsEmptyValue %></p>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></ul>    
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p><%# Eval("Key") %> / <%# Eval("Value") %></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p>Status: <%= this.IntDicIsEmptyValue%></p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And my .cs File:

```
public Dictionary<int,string> intdic;
public string IntDicIsEmptyValue { get; set; }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntDicIsEmptyValue = "Is Empty";
    intdic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    //Comment next two lines to see Emptydatatemplate with IsEmpty
    intdic.Add(3, "Three");
    intdic.Add(4, "Four");

    ListView1.DataSource = intdic;
    ListView1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: dumb question , answered it myself,,, used variable from page load instead of public/private on page
hehe... thanks